# How exactly do casinos come up with their probabilities?

Tags: probability, logic, random

Recently I was diving into the world that is casinos and while looking at all the games, I seemed to focus on the slot-machine side of things. (Primarily due to the technology side of it.)

While reading up about the odds, different types of slots, how they work, etc... I noticed one common thing. While the game itself tells you; "You will win x amount with these combinations."
Casinos seem to be very quiet when it comes to discussing actual percentages. I assume they do this since when someone sees that their chance to win a large amount is 0.000001%, it could deter them from using the machine?

Presumably, I assume they take a range of numbers like; 12,000. Take their number of payouts, then assign the payouts to a sub-range of that first range. 
For example; Payout 1 = 5, 24, 2356, 8000, etc... Then they just use a RNG to determine the outcome?

Anyway, with that in mind I started to brainstorm and try and make my own "odds/probabilities" for a classic three-reel slot-machine.
Something that has given me some trouble is sourcing some actual information. As said above, casinos are pretty hush, hush about actual numbers.

So, my question is; "How do casinos come up with their probabilities?"
For example; Let's say a casino wants to start a new machine, and they start allocating percentages to their payouts.

Is it as simple as them just picking a random super low percentage? Or are they actually basing it off some kind of formula?

Another follow up question I had, do they play the same odds/percentages on all reels or would they dynamically change the odds on the 2nd and 3rd reel based on the outcome of the 1st reel? (If so that seems a little dodgy???)

Any help/information is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: By now, I'm pretty sure that a lot of behavioral psychology goes into the design of casino games but from a pure mathematical point of view the main thing the casino cares about is that (from their point of view) the slot machine has a positive [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value). (To some extent they also care about variance, but since high variance is what many gamblers seek, that's much more of a trade-off.)

Comment: It is easier than you think: let's say you want to pay 10000\$ for a combination, the machine will have a bag that accumulate the gambles so that, when they overcome 12000\$ the combination will be issued, whichever the choice of the player.

Comment: @N74 If that were the case, there would be an incredibly simple winning strategy for the player by observing the machines. Hence I'm very doubtful that this is the case. Do you have a source to back up your claim?

Comment: It is nothing more than a martingale for "the player", as you would need 12000 games to be sure to win. Anyway, somewhere in my backups, I have the source code for a poker-like game that worked exactly as I stated.

Comment: Assuming the slots are not fixed,then there would be $n^3$ possible outcomes, where n is the number of possibilities for each wheel (assuming n distinct possibilities - each occurring once)..  Then  they would assign a payout to each outcome with the average less than $n^3$.  Based on my limited knowledge, I believe the average is around $n^3/2$.

Comment: Some info here: https://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/clins/my_job_is_writing_software_for_slot_machines_and/?utm_source=amp&utm_medium=comment_list